# Recurring Discount Calculation

Tags: cognito-forms

I need my form to give a free ticket to every 20th attendee.  So far I have:

```
=TotalMealTickets>20 ? 1:FreeTickets
```

How do I make it multiply free tickets for every 20 people?

Answer (score 0):

I am with Cognito Forms Support.

To determine how many discounts or free tickets you may need to provide, use this calculation:

```
=Math.Floor(TotalMealTickets / 20)
```

If you need more assistance, please submit a [support request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/) and provide a link to your form.